# Django Wagtail: Do we have any option to edit list_display of any Page model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, wagtail

I would like to ask you If there is any option how to edit **"list_display"** of any Wagtail page model. I would assume that there must be something because we can add custom model into sidebar using

```
wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.options.ModelAdmin
```

For example I can add my **Email** model into **admin.py** or **hooks.py** like this

```
class EmailAdmin(ModelAdmin):

    model = Email        
    menu_label = "Emails"
    menu_icon = "mail"
    menu_order = 200
    add_to_settings_menu = False
    exclude_from_explorer = False
    empty_value_display = 'N/A'
    list_per_page = 10        
    list_display = ('subject', 'name_surname', 'phone', 'email', 'text_', 'date', 'sent', 'change_seen')

    def name_surname(self,obj):
        return "{0} {1}".format(obj.name, obj.surname)
```

In that class **EmailAdmin** I can build custom **list_display**. Can we adjust wagtail Page models by similar way?
Thank you very much in advance.

[image]

**EDIT:**
So far I overcome it using ModelAdmin, I registered my BlogPage models into Wagtail sidebar, where I have more freedom to show more information. For example I am tracking how many times blog post was viewed.

**admin.py**

```
from wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.options import ModelAdmin, modeladmin_register, ModelAdminGroup

from .models import BlogPostPage, PostAdvancedPage

class BlogPostPageAdmin(ModelAdmin):

    model = BlogPostPage 
    menu_label = "Standard Blog posts"
    menu_icon = "doc-full"    

    add_to_settings_menu = False
    exclude_from_explorer = False
    empty_value_display = 'N/A'
    list_per_page = 10
    index_view_extra_css = ["css/wagtail.css",]
    list_display = ('title','slug', 'first_published_at', 'owner', 'categories_', 'visited')

    def categories_(self,obj):
        cats = obj.categories.all()
        cats_str = [x.name for x in cats]
        return ', '.join(cats_str)

class PostAdvancedPageAdmin(ModelAdmin):

    model = PostAdvancedPage   
    menu_label = "Advanced Blog posts"
    menu_icon = "doc-full"

    add_to_settings_menu = False
    exclude_from_explorer = False
    empty_value_display = 'N/A'
    list_per_page = 10
    index_view_extra_css = ["css/wagtail.css",]
    list_display = ('title','slug', 'first_published_at', 'owner', 'categories_', 'visited')

    def categories_(self,obj):
        cats = obj.categories.all()
        cats_str = [x.name for x in cats]
        return ', '.join(cats_str)

class ViewGroup(ModelAdminGroup):
    menu_label = 'OverView'
    menu_icon = 'view'  # change as required
    menu_order = 200  # will put in 3rd place (000 being 1st, 100 2nd)
    items = (BlogPostPageAdmin, PostAdvancedPageAdmin)

modeladmin_register(ViewGroup)
```

**Result so far:**
[image]

Comment: There isn't an easy way to do this - these columns [are hard coded](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/admin/templates/wagtailadmin/pages/listing/_table_headers_explore.html). You would have to override Wagtail's page listing templates if you wanted to add something else here.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. I overcame that using ModelAdmin, I've just registered my BlogPage models into sidebar and I have more freedom.